# Python: Delete CSV headers row and rewrite new headers row

Tags: python, csv, header

Still teaching myself python so please don't hate me if my code is terrible...

My code:

```
ifile = csv.reader(open("TE.csv",'rb'))
shutil.copy("TE.csv","temp")
tempfile = csv.reader(open("temp","rb"))
ofile = csv.writer(open("TE-RESULTS.csv","ab"))

for row in ifile:
    #do some web scraping stuff here

    VC_s = str(cells[1].find(text=True))
    VC_i = str(cells[2].find(text=True))
    VT_s = str(cells[4].find(text=True))

    entry = [VC_s, VC_i, VT_s]

    rowAdd = tempfile.next()
    ofile.writerow(rowAdd + entry)
```

Problem: I start with a CSV that I will have to add 3 columns to the end. Using my code above, I get the following output:

```
HEADER1     HEADER2    HEADER3   result1   result2   result3
autocheck   C:\check   1.jpg     result1   result2   result3
services    C:\svcs    2.jpg     result1   result2   result3
```

My ***DESIRED*** output:

```
HEADER1     HEADER2    HEADER3   HEADER4   HEADER5   HEADER6
autocheck   C:\check   1.jpg     result1   result2   result3
services    C:\svcs    2.jpg     result1   result2   result3
```

What is the best way to fix my code that will give me the desired output? My initial thought would be to delete the HEADERS row and replace it with a new HEADERS row in the TE-RESULTS.csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process the header row before the for loop.

```
rowAdd = tempfile.next()
ofile.writerow(rowAdd + ['HEADER4', 'HEADER5', 'HEADER6'])

for ...
```

Comment: Thanks but now the output is repeating the first three headers in each row. I've been able to fix this by changing the last portion like so: `rowAdd2 = tempfile.next() ofile.writerow(rowAdd2 + entry)
`  but it gives me a StopIteration error. How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you put the code in the answer *before* the for loop, or inside it?

Comment: Before the loop like the answer you gave. it's right before the 'for row in ifile:'

Comment: It shouldn't have been repeating the headers then. And the reason you're getting StopIteration is because..... wait, why are you copying `TE.csv` to `temp` and then opening both, when you should just be using `row` instead of `rowAdd`?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I removed the `temp` file and changed them to `row` instead of `rowAdd`.This works perfectly now!